# Selecting multiple row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

```
Product
------------------------------
productID | productName
------------------------------
1  | Banana
2  | Apple
3  | Pie
4  | Dragon Fruit
5  | Watermelon
6  | Kiwi
7  | Nugget

Purchase
-------------------------------------
purchaseID | productID | purchaserID
-------------------------------------
1          |1          |1
2          |2          |1
3          |3          |1
4          |4          |2
5          |5          |2
6          |2          |4
7          |1          |5
```

How do I get the purchaserID (purchaserID 1) who buy productID 1 AND 2 AND 3 from Purchase table? TYVM!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: tried actually. But it's different set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  A flexible approach is to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select purchaserId
from purchases
where productid in (1, 2, 3)
group by purchaserId
having count(distinct productid) = 3;
```